# Usando Iconfiguration en MSTest Pruebas Mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jsonobject, unittest, .net-6.0

Buenas noches comunidad

Perdonen alguien sabe cual es la mejor manera de usar, generar, enviar el archivo appsettings.json en una clase de Test, ya que actualmente quiero realizar una prueba mock a una clase de lógica pero al instanciarla me pide el objeto Iconfiguration, entiendo que este iconfiguration es la información del archivo  appsettings.json de la webAPI, pero al estar en la capa, clase Test no tengo acceso a este archivo ni puedo verlo.

Esto en webAPI Net 6.0 c#

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar un proveedor de configuración en memoria

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
...
...

var enMemoria = new Dictionary<string, string>{ { "llavejwt", "klsdjlfksdjlkfjsdlkd" } };
 
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                 .AddInMemoryCollection(enMemoria)
                                 .Build();
        
var cuentasController = new CuentasController(configuration);
```